# Encoding Data to a utf8 string fails

Tags: swift, encoding

I'm trying to encode a float array to a utf8 string so that I can send it over the network. To do that I'm

1. trying to first get its binary representation and then
2. I'm encoding that data using `String(data:data, encoding: .utf8)`

but it is returning nil. What would cause a conversion like that to fail? There are some cases where it succeeds (ex: initializing the array with test data `let depthMap =[[Float]](repeating: [Float](repeating: 10.5, count: 480), count: 64)`) but when using random floats, it fails.

Here's the full code snippet:

```swift
let depthMap:[[Float]] = [] //This is a 2D array filled with depth data from the phone's true depth camera
let arrayOfEncodedData = depthMap.compactMap { floatArray in
    let data = Data(bytes: floatArray, count: floatArray.count * MemoryLayout<Float>.stride)
    let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) //returns nil
    return string
}
```

Comment: Arbitrary binary data *isn't* UTF-8-encoded text. If you want to represent arbitrary binary data as text, it's usually best to use base64.

Comment: After a little bit of research that makes a lot of sense and I feel a little bit like a fool.

Comment: Our field is _full_ of learning opportunities — and you don't know until you learn. No need to feel like a fool!

Comment: See also [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1053/) ;)